# Display non-ASCII character in ImageJ

Tags: java, macros, imagej

Simple question but I can't find the answer anywhere. No search strategy so far has worked for me.

I have an ImageJ macro that opens a dialog for users to set the size of an image overlay. The dialog prompts users to provide the size of the overlay in microns:

```
Dialog.addNumber("Width (µm):", 500);
Dialog.addNumber("Height (µm):", 250);
```

The problem is that the dialog doesn't display as expected: There is an extra character printed in front of the micron symbol. Instead of this (µm), I get this (¬µm).

It's a character encoding issue, clearly. But I can't find any documentation anywhere telling me how to properly insert a non-ASCII character into an ImageJ dialog. I've tried using ASCII code (230) and Unicode (U+00B5) in every way I can think of, but in those cases it simply renders as code rather than a symbol. There are macro calls in ImageJ to obtain a Unicode string for a character, but there is no way to print it back except as a string of numbers? I'm stumped.

Comment: I can't reproduce this myself - the µ appears fine, with no preceding character.  Could you update your question with (a) the version of ImageJ you're using (b) the version of Java you're using and (c) the operating system?  (a) and (b) can be found via `Help > About ImageJ`

Comment: Using ImageJ 1.45s, Java 1.6.0_31 64 bit, OS X 10.7.3.

Comment: What is the encoding, `file -I`, of you macro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you do is this:

```
Dialog.addNumber("Width (" + fromCharCode(181) + "m):", 500);
Dialog.addNumber("Height (" + fromCharCode(181) + "m):", 250);
```

where `181` is the decimal value of hexidecimal `00B5`